# "Set" a keyboard layout by pressing Shift key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

**Preamble:**
On Windows I use a program which allow me to set English keyboard layout on pressing Left Shift and my local keyboard layout on pressing Right Shift. Not cyclic switching is very convenient as I don't need to remember which layout is active, I only need to know in what language I'm going to write now.

**Question:**
How do I set not cyclic but direct turning on a keyboard layout by pressing Left/Right Shift key?

**Environment**

Ubuntu: 22.10

GNOME: 43.0

Windowing system: Wayland

Comment: In this scenario, how do you type capital letters?

Comment: Holding Shift does the work and if any other symbol was typed no layout changing performed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative idea:

Both shift keys cycle two layouts + Caps Lock LED On

`setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option grp:shifts_toggle -option grp_led:caps`